# Whenever gem not working rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I had followed the Whenever tutorials and installed the gem. I'm using Ubuntu. I have written this method in the model:

```
def self.cron_job
  puts "am in cron"
  InspectionReport.all
  logger.info Time.now.to_s
  InspectionReport.all.each do |ins|
    ins.date = ins.date+1.month
    ins.save!
  end
end
```

Code in schedule.rb:

```
set :output, "/log/cron.log" 
every 1.minute do   
runner "InspectionReport.cron_job", :environment => :development  
rake update_inspection_reports end
```

Nothing happens after a minute. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in schedule.rb file. it is working for me:

```
#for default path related issue
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

every 1.minute do
  runner "InspectionReport.cron_job", :output => 'log/cron.log'
  rake update_inspection_reports , :output => 'log/cron.log'
end
```